# quick fill forms in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Sorry I have a really basic question while learning Django and could not find an easy answer.

My model is :

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    type = models.CharField(max_length= 200)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now= False, auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now= True, auto_now_add= False)
    description = models.TextField()
```

And so my general form implementation is :

```
class EntryForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Entry
    fields = ['name','type', 'description']
```

views:

```
def add(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EntryForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            instance.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')      
    else:
        form = EntryForm()

    return render(request, "form.html", {'form': form})
```

I want to add a quick fill button next to add button (that calls above view ) where the name and type is statically filled in the object and only textbox appears for description field.

I could not find a way to statically assign the values to my field in Django.

I had tried creating a different HTML file ( quickform.html) but  {{form.as_p}} will put all the fields.

my forms.html is

```
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}

        <button class="btn btn-success" type='submit'>Submit</button>   
    </form>
```

what would be the best way to add a quick link to my index page where the name ( is auto-filled to the "general"+str(id)) and type is auto-filled to "general") is auto-filled and does not appear in the form page

Comment: How is this different from setting a `default` value for the model field

Comment: @BhavaniRavi because in future i would have more buttons that will decide the type of the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion the easiest way to do such a thing is to add **on click** event to your second button then write a simple **javascript** function the fills the elements you want with static values.